# Пузырьковая сортировка в питоне

Tags: python, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Мне нужно добавить элементы с массива который я отсортировала в новый массив, не совсем понимаю куда применить функцию append.
Сам код:

```
a = [1,6,8,5,3]
b = []
n = len(a)
for i in range(n-1):
     for j in range(0, n-i-1):
           if a[j] < a[j + 1]:
                a[j], a[j + 1] = a[j + 1], a[j]

print(b)
```

В массиве b хочу результат [8,6,5,3,1]

Answer (score 1):

`append` нигде не надо применять, так как у вас сортируется и изменяется массив `a`. Вы можете избавиться от `b` и возвращать `a`.

Если нужно сохранить исходный массив, копируйте его в `b` и выполняйте изменения уже в нем.

```
a = [1,6,8,5,3]
b = a.copy()
n = len(b)
for i in range(n-1):
     for j in range(0, n-i-1):
           if b[j] < b[j + 1]:
                b[j], b[j + 1] = b[j + 1], b[j]

print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = [1,6,8,5,3]
b = []
n = len(a)
for i in range(n-1):
     for j in range(0, n-i-1):
           if a[j] < a[j + 1]:
                a[j], a[j + 1] = a[j + 1], a[j]

b = a.copy()
print(b)
```

Улучшенный вариант Вашей сортировки:

```py
a = [1,6,8,5,3]
b = []
n = len(a)
for i in range(1, n):
     flag = False
     for j in range(0, n-i):
           if a[j] < a[j + 1]:
                a[j], a[j + 1] = a[j + 1], a[j]
                flag = True
     if flag not is True:
         break

b = a.copy()
print(b)
```